# Remove A string from B string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have manufacture name and a product name which has manufacture name and I want to remove manufacture name form product name, I use the following code but didn't work

I tried both sub and replace methods but didn't work

```
import re

menufacture_name = "AMPHENOL ICC (COMMERCIAL PRODUCTS)"

product_name = "AMPHENOL ICC (COMMERCIAL PRODUCTS) - D-SUB CONNECTOR, PLUG, 9POS"

// product_name = re.sub(menufacture_name + " - ", "", product_name)
product_name.replace(menufacture_name + " - ", '')

print("Product name : " + product_name)
```

This should be the result
Product name : D-SUB CONNECTOR, PLUG, 9POS

Comment: product_name = product_name.replace(menufacture_name + " - ", '')

Comment: [Python strings are immutable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), so you cannot modify an existing string. That's why `replace` will not replace in-place.

Comment: Why not just `product_name = product_name[len(manufacturer_name) + 3:]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strings are immutable**. Your code is correct just that you forgot to assign the `replace` back to the string.

```
product_name = product_name.replace(menufacture_name + " - ", '')
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` doesn't replace the current string. It will return a copy of the modified string.

Note: **In Python strings are immutable**.

Try like below:

```
modified_string = product_name.replace(menufacture_name + " - ", '')

print("Product name : " + modified_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, you just have to assign the result of the replace, because the original string is *not* modified in-place (strings are immutable in Python, so all string operations return a new one instead):

```
product_name = product_name.replace(menufacture_name, "").strip("- ")

product_name
=> 'D-SUB CONNECTOR, PLUG, 9POS'
```

Notice that I used `strip()` to remove the extra `"- "` characters from one side, so the output string will look nicer.